# Javascript assign object vs copying properties

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-management

I have an application that makes frequent AJAX calls to fetch an (associative) array in JSON format. On each AJAX result I need to update my current array based on the new JSON result.

How will the following approaches be different in memory consumption and garbage collection?

1. Assign each element of array (object) directly to the target array. i.e. `myArray[ID].data = jsonData[ID]`
2. Assign properties one by one for each object. i.e. `myArray[ID].data[prop] = jsonData[ID][prop]`

---

Array structure

```
// Format of my data in the page
myArray = {'ID1': {'dom-el': dom-el, 'data': data-object}} 

// Format of JSON data through AJAX request
jsonData = {'ID1': data-object,... }
```

Comment: assigning reference vs assigning primitive - is that what you are asking? copying primitives one by one will always be slower and heavier on memory.

Comment: @webduvet that is good to know, but I am asking about how the memory consumption would be affected in both cases. And how the objects will be garbage collected. I think I will rewrite the question.

Comment: if you assign the new object like `oldObject.data = newArray`. Then whatever was oldObject.data referencing to it will be eligible for garbage collection as long as you do not have any the variable pointing to it.